QGIS copy fields in empty geopackage or reset FID
How to copy all fields and styles in a new geopackage without features? I will create a new geopackage. I´ve saved the style from an other geopackage and import this in a new geopackage. All styles and expressions will be there in the new one, but the fields are missing. I can activate the fields in export/saving a style.
When I export a geopackage, I will get all the fields, but the features are also inside. I can delete these features in the new one, but the "fid" won´t reset to 1.


I would try ogr2ogr with the -limit parameter https://gdal.org/en/latest/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-limit.
ogr2ogr -f gpkg empty_tables.gpkg input.gpkg -limit 0

Resetting the fid from an existing SQLite/GeoPackage means resetting the SQLite rownum, and when the table is empty it should work by deleting the corresponding sequense.
delete from sqlite_sequence where name='your_table';

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601697/sqlite-reset-primary-key-field
Be careful and have backups.

OK, I thought it´s easier. I don´t know how to use ogr2ogr or sqglite.

But for what is the layerstyle checkbox "fields"? I thought I can create a new geopackage, load the layer style and all is done.

I can see a hint under the title of the "fields" option: "Virtual fields, aliases, default value expressions and constraints from the form section and WMS/WFS exposure"

OK, I did it with DB Browser SQLite. I duplicate the gpkg, open it in DB Browser, delete all entries and set the sequence back. I don´t understand, why there is no function inside of QGIS. A simple "export without features and reset fid" checkbox while export. Or a plugin for this procedere. Or like the style export a field/table export und load function. (When multiple layers with same table structure will become the same new fields with a saved style. Now I must do this job in every layer to add a new field.)

Perhaps your use case is not so common. For example, why do you feel resetting fid necessary? And exporting without features feels uncommon as well.
